# I can't add apostrophe in string when importing Excel file into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache, apache-poi

below i have attached my program , while importing from excel to mysql everything is fine for me except in text eg : am using can't,don't,it's in this  apostrophe will not accepting in mysql its showing

```
package importdata;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;


public class ImportData {

    /**
     * @param args
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ExcelInfo","root","root");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D://check.xls");
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
           // XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
            //XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Row row;
            for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                int id = (int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                String name = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String address = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO checking VALUES('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+address+"')";
                pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.execute();
                System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
            }
            con.commit();
            pstm.close();
            con.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i am getting this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's')' at line 1

Comment: Please add your error into your original post and not as a comment.  Also, you haven't asked a question.  Do you want to remove the apostrophes?  Do you want to keep them in?  How do you expect this code to function?

Comment: hai andrew i am new to stackoverflow and this is my 1st post , i want to keep them in , due to apostrophe am getting a error

Answer (score 4):

The apostrophe character is the same character as the single-quote character used in SQL to delimit string literals.  The apostrophe is considered the end of the string value, messing up the parsing.  (This is also one way how SQL injection works.)

You're already using `PreparedStatement`.  Take advantage of the placeholders feature.  This also takes care of the apostrophe-is-single-quote issue.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO checking VALUES(?,?,?)";
pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstm.setInt(1, id);
pstm.setString(2, name);
pstm.setString(3, address);
pstm.execute();
```

Comment: very thankx @rgettman and its working fine , 1 more help i uploaded 116500 rows and its showing a error like this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space , now wat will i do